# Yup validation access parent.parent

Tags: javascript, forms, yup

I'm using `yup` module for validate my form. I would like access to parent for test the value.

My schema :

```
enabled: yup.boolean(),
contactDetail: yup.object().shape({
  phoneNumber1: yup.string().nullable(),
  phoneNumber2: yup.string().nullable(),
  email: yup.string().test('email', 'test', async function() {
    // test enabled value
  })
}),
```

The method `when` can access on same level, not the parent.

Anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @NidaMunir I have added my answer. This might help you :)

Answer (score 13):

I came through similar issue. I used this workthrough with success.

**Idea**: Pass whole form-data as a context to the schema and access any form value using

**`this.options.context`**

```
  const schema = yup.object().shape({
        enabled: yup.boolean(),
        contactDetail: yup.object().shape({
          phoneNumber1: yup.string().nullable(),
          phoneNumber2: yup.string().nullable(),
          email: yup.string().test('email', 'test', async function () {
            // this.options.context.enabled
           
          }),
        }),
      });
```

> Passing Context

**Without Formik**

Send your **Form data** as a context while validating

```
 schema.validateSync(data, {context: form_data})
```

**With Formik**

Use **validate** instead of **validationSchema**

Pass your **Form data** as 4th argument in **validateYupSchema** which represents context and can be accessed later in schema.

Pass your **schema** as 2nd argument in **validateYupSchema**.

```
    <Formik
      validate={(value) => {
        try {
          validateYupSchema(value, schema, true, value);
        } catch (err) {
          return yupToFormErrors(err); //for rendering validation errors
        }

        return {};
      }}

       onSubmit={} />
```

Following is for the asynchronous validation with Formik.

```
    <Formik
      validate={async (value) => {
        try {
          await validateYupSchema(value, schema, false, value);
        } catch (err) {
          return yupToFormErrors(err); //for rendering validation errors
        }

        return {};
      }}

       onSubmit={} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the test method available in the https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedtestname-string-message-string--function-test-function-schema .
like below example, you can access one level of parent details inside test() using this.parent.

```
amount: Yup.string().test('amount-test3', 'amount is required', function (value) {
                    const { description } = this.parent;
                    return !(!!description && !Number(value));
                  })
```

Comment: `this.parent` also returns the siblings, and not the parents siblings (parent.parent)